# Getting Error: Cannot find module './src/init' when trying to initialize a react native app

Tags: npm, react-native, npm-install

When I try to install react native with the command `react-native init ProjectName`

I get the following:

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\Users\Xegano\Documents\ProjectName
Installing react-native package from npm...
Setting up new React Native app in C:\Users\Xegano\Documents\ProjectName
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/init'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Xegano\Documents\ProjectName\node_modules\gulp-sourcemaps\index.js:4:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\Xegano\Documents\ProjectName\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

Why does this happen? It used to work earlier the only thing I remember I changed is some packages from the SDK Manager. Could it be that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp-sourcemaps: Cannot find module './src/init'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030923/gulp-sourcemaps-cannot-find-module-src-init)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in [gulp-sourcemaps 2.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps@2.1.0), which has been recently released. Here is an issue for it on GitHub: https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/238. I believe it should be fixed soon, meanwhile you can downgrade it to 2.0.x or 1.7.x.

Update: Thanks to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10375#issuecomment-253649977) I was able to make it work with the following steps:

```
$ mkdir MyProject
$ cd MyProject
$ npm i gulp-sourcemaps@1.7
$ cd ..
$ react-native init MyProject # answer yes
```

Comment: Thanks, explains a lot

Answer (score 4):

Actually it worked in my case but I was required to downgrade gulp-sourcemaps to version 1.7

```
$ cd MyProject
$ rm -rf node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps
$ npm install gulp-sourcemaps@1.7
$ cd ..
$ react-native init MyProject
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed "src" was not included in package.json.
https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/238

Comment: Is it really fixed? As I keep on getting error still!