# gulp-sourcemaps: Cannot find module './src/init'

Tags: gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I get an error while installing React-native, I have tried to search for an answer, but I can not find one.

When running "react-native init meet" I get this error:

```
    This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/alfred/React/meet
Installing react-native package from npm...
Setting up new React Native app in /Users/alfred/React/meet
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/init'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alfred/React/meet/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/index.js:4:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/alfred/React/meet/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I don't really get what is wrong...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's related to an issue with gulp-sourcemaps recent deployment https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/238

A project maintainer says at the end of the thread that he'll get to it today and

> For the time being lock your version down to 2.0.x or 1.7.x

To fix, add specific version in your `package.json` until the issue is fixed:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.7.x"
  }
}
```

Use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to prevent similar issues in the future.

Comment: I've just run into this problem, except gulp-sourcemaps is pulled in by another package (presumably Laravel Elixir or Webpack). How can I change the version of gulp-sourcemaps without breaking future `npm update`?

Comment: Use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). Very helpful in such situations which are not rare, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a recent change in `gulp-sourcemaps`.  See bug here: https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/238

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed. Run npm install
https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/238