# React Native init MyProject throw error

Tags: react-native

I am now studying React Native. I can create the RN Project by executing command `react-native init myProject` successfully before. But today I do the same job , I got an error:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './src/init'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Blain/Desktop/ReactNative/RNScrollView/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/index.js:4:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Blain/Desktop/ReactNative/RNScrollView/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Please help me to solve this problem , TKS. By the way, My Mac os is macOS Sierra 10.12

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40030716/5496231). Maybe this is the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Hey Blain, stoked you got your answer! You should mark it as accepted so that @李振纲 can get the cred and others can have a reference.